Show View and Then Hide It In 2 Seconds
I am using the following View Modifier in SwiftUI to create a hide modifier. It looks like this:
struct Hide: ViewModifier {
    
    let delay: Double
    @State private var isVisible = true
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .opacity(isVisible ? 1 : 0)
            .onAppear {
                
                // Reset the visibility to true and then hide it after the delay
                withAnimation {
                    isVisible = true
                }
                
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + delay) {
                    withAnimation {
                        isVisible = false
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func hide(in delay: Double) -> some View {
        modifier(Hide(delay: delay))
    }
}

I use it as shown below:
 if !message.isEmpty {
                Text("ERROR")
                    .hide(in: 2.0)
            }

This only works for the first time. I think the isVisible state is not getting reset properly. Any ideas what I am doing wrong? I really don't want to pass any Binding to the Hide modifier.
UPDATE:
Here is the code that triggers the hide view modifier
struct LoginScreenContainer: View {
    
    @State private var message: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Message") {
                message = "Error Message"
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            if !message.isEmpty {
                Text("ERROR")
                    .hide(in: 2.0)
            }
        }
    }
}


What do you mean by "first time"? How do you trigger it a "second time"? Please show a [mcve].

@Sweeper I added the code to show how the hide function is called.

Why don't you want to pass a Binding? Base on your use case here, it isn't really a "hide", but a "show momentarily with a trigger".

@Sweeper Yes. You are right. I ended up using the Binding.

You can have the view modifier detect a change in a value, and re-show the view when that changes.
struct ShowMomentarily<Trigger: Equatable>: ViewModifier {
    
    let duration: Duration
    let trigger: Trigger
    @State private var isVisible = false // initially not visible
    @State private var initial = true
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .opacity(isVisible ? 1 : 0)
            .task(id: trigger) {
                // do not do the task on the first appearance
                if initial {
                    initial = false
                    return
                }
                
                isVisible = true
                do {
                    try await Task.sleep(for: duration)
                    isVisible = false
                } catch {
                    // this means the task has been cancelled
                    // e.g. 'trigger' changes again before the duration ended
                }
            }
            .animation(.default, value: isVisible)
    }
}

extension View {
    func show(for delay: Duration, trigger: some Equatable) -> some View {
        modifier(ShowMomentarily(duration: delay, trigger: trigger))
    }
}

Here is an example usage, using message as the trigger, and the button assigns a randomly generated string so the trigger changes every time.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var message: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Message") {
                message = UUID().uuidString
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Text(message)
                .show(for: .seconds(2), trigger: message)
        }
    }
}

This "trigger" pattern can be seen in many existing APIs like sensoryFeedback and phaseAnimator.
Note that I removed the if !message.isEmpty check. This is because controlling visibility using if and opacity at the same time is quite messy, since their animations are controlled differently. It would be much simpler to just have a single trigger.
If you assign the same string to message a second time, nothing is changed. message is still "Error Message", so SwiftUI does not update anything. If you need to support this case, you can use a different @State as the trigger.
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var message: String = ""
    @State private var trigger = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Button("Show Message") {
                message = UUID().uuidString
                trigger.toggle()
            }
        }
        .overlay(alignment: .bottom) {
            Text(message)
                .show(for: .seconds(2), trigger: trigger)
        }
    }
}


Another way to implement this effect is as a View with a binding to the message. After the delay, the binding can be reset, which prepares the stage for showing another message (which can be the same message again).
Instead of using an asynchronous task to update the flag, you can add a delay to the animation. Resetting the message can be performed as a completion callback after the (delayed)  animation has completed.
struct DisappearingMessage: View {
    @Binding var message: String
    let delay: Double
    @State private var isVisible = true

    var body: some View {
        Text(message)
            .opacity(isVisible ? 1 : 0)
            .animation(.easeInOut.delay(delay), value: isVisible)
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation {
                    isVisible.toggle()
                } completion: {
                    message = ""
                }
            }
    }
}

To use, just substitute the Text + modifier that you had in your original code with DisappearingMessage:
if !message.isEmpty {
    DisappearingMessage(message: $message, delay: 2.0)
}

You will see that DisappearingMessage is using an .onAppear callback like you were using before, so the lifetime of DisappearingMessage is expected to be limited to the presentation of one message only.
You might prefer to keep DisappearingMessage showing and just update the message value to show a new message. Using it this way, some small changes would be needed:

remove the if statement if !message.isEmpty, so that DisappearingMessage is always shown
the animation duration and animation delay should depend on the value of the flag isVisible 
use .onChange instead of .onAppear to respond to changes to the message
reset the flag isVisible in the completion callback.

Here is the updated body of DisappearingMessage that works in this more general-purpose way:
Text(message)
    .opacity(isVisible ? 1 : 0)
    .animation(
        .easeInOut(duration: isVisible ? 0 : 0.3)
        .delay(isVisible ? 0 : delay),
        value: isVisible
    )
    .onChange(of: message, initial: true) { oldVal, newVal in
        if isVisible, !newVal.isEmpty {
            withAnimation {
                isVisible = false
            } completion: {
                message = ""
                isVisible = true
            }
        }
    }

